# UIBezierPath in a zoomable view not pixelated

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibezierpath

I have a ScrollView in a ViewController and on the ScrollView i have a View. I use that view for drawing something like rect, circle, line, text,... 
For drawing i use a UIBezierPath.
The problem is when i zoom into the view (that is subview of the scrollview) circle, line and rect are pixelated.
I use a UIScrollViewDelegate method for zooming in this way:
Remember: mapview is the view that is subview of scrollview!!

```
#pragma mark *** ScrollView Delegate ***

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollview
{
    [mapview setNeedsDisplay]; // Redraw scrollview content while scrolling
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return mapview;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    view.contentScaleFactor =  scale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

}
```

Whit this code i obtain this:

(I cannot post the image now because i have not enough reputation!!)

The rect is not pixelated but the circle and the line yes.
How can i resolve?
Is ok to use UIBezierPath for my situation?
I want to draw vectorial graphic element (line, circle, rect) and zoom on the view in which these object are drawn without pixelated!!!

My DrawRect implementation:

```
if ([type isEqualToString:@"rect"])
        {
            MAPRect *rect = [[MAPRect alloc]init];
            rect.bounds = [self getBoundsForElement:properties];
            UIBezierPath *rectPath = [rect bezierPathForDrawing];
            if (![[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"] isEqual:@"NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 1"])
            {
                CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"]]; //representation: r0.539924 g0.611259 b1.000000 a1.000000
                UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor];
                [rect setStrokeColor:color];
                [[rect strokeColor] set];
            }
            else
            {
                CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"]];

                [[UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor] set];
            }
            [rectPath stroke];
            if (![[properties valueForKey:@"fillColor"] isEqual:@"NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 1 1"])
            {
                CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[properties valueForKey:@"fillColor"]]; //representation: r0.539924 g0.611259 b1.000000 a1.000000
                UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor];
                [rect setFillColor:color];
                [[rect fillColor] set];
                [rectPath fill];
            }
        }

        else if ([type isEqualToString:@"circle"])
        {
            MAPCircle *circle = [[MAPCircle alloc]init];
            //circle.bounds = [self getBoundsForElement:properties];
            circle.bounds = CGRectInset([self getBoundsForElement:properties], 5.0, 5.0);
            UIBezierPath *circlePath = [circle bezierPathForDrawing];


            if (![[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"] isEqual:@"NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 1"])
            {
                CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"]]; //representation: r0.539924 g0.611259 b1.000000 a1.000000
                UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor];
                [circle setStrokeColor:color];
                [[circle strokeColor] set];
            }
            else
            {
                CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"]];

                [[UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor] set];
            }
            [circlePath stroke];
            if (![[properties valueForKey:@"fillColor"] isEqual:@"NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 1 1"])
            {
                CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[properties valueForKey:@"fillColor"]]; //representation: r0.539924 g0.611259 b1.000000 a1.000000
                UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor];
                [circle setFillColor:color];
                [[circle fillColor] set];
                [circlePath fill];
            }

        }

        else if ([type isEqualToString:@"line"])
        {
            MAPLine *line = [[MAPLine alloc]init];
            line.bounds = [self getBoundsForElement:properties];
            UIBezierPath *linePath = [line bezierPathForDrawing];
            if (![[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"] isEqual:@"NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 1"])
            {
                CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"]]; //representation: r0.539924 g0.611259 b1.000000 a1.000000
                UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor];
                [line setStrokeColor:color];
                [[line strokeColor] set];
            }
            else
            {
                CIColor *coreColor = [CIColor colorWithString:[properties valueForKey:@"strokeColor"]];

                [[UIColor colorWithCIColor:coreColor] set];
            }
            [linePath stroke];
        }

        else if ([type isEqualToString:@"text"])
        {
            MAPText *text = [[MAPText alloc]init];
            text.bounds = [self getBoundsForElement:properties];
            UILabel *textfield = [text getTextField];
            [textfield setText:[properties valueForKey:@"textContent"]];
            [textfield sizeToFit];
            if (self.subviews.count == j)
            {
                [self addSubview:textfield];
            }

            j ++;

        }
```

where MAPRECT, MAPCIRCLE, MAPLINE, MAPTEXT are classes that i used for implement tha drawing of the element, for example MAPCIRCLE class is like this:

```
#import "MAPCircle.h"

@implementation MAPCircle

- (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathForDrawing
{

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:[self bounds]];
    [path setLineWidth:[self strokeWidth]];
    return path;

}

@end
```

> Blockquote

Comment: It might help to add your drawRect implementation too.

Comment: ok i added the drawrect implementation in my question above .